# How to store unique data from excel to database(using apache poi)?

Tags: java, database, apache-poi

How to store unique data from cells(for example phone number and email Id should be unique) in excel to database if there exist multiple duplicate values in the sheet (using apache poi)?

below is the code to read excel data and send it to mysql database

public class ExcelToDatabase {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, IOException {
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName","root","root");
    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
    
    
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/home/ist/Proj/ApachePOI/datafiles/TestData.xlsx");
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    
    int rows = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    
    for(int r=1; r<=rows; r++) {
        
        XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(r);
        double EmpId = row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue();
        String fName = row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
        String lName = row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
        int Age = (int) row.getCell(3).getNumericCellValue();
        String Email = row.getCell(4).getStringCellValue();
        String Phone = row.getCell(5).getStringCellValue();
        
        
        String sql = "INSERT INTO table_name values('"+EmpId+"','"+fName+"','"+lName+"', '"+Age+"','"+Email+"', '"+Phone+"')";
        statement.execute(sql);
        statement.execute("commit");
        
    }
    workbook.close();
    fis.close();
    con.close();
    
    System.out.println("data has been exported to the Database");
}
```

Comment: One approach is to read the excel data as you are doing and store the email field in HashSet. Then iterate the HashSet to store in your DB. Also, I noticed you are committing your transaction after every insert statement. This is not a good practice unless your business login demands this.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, IOException {
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName","root","root");
    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
    
    
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/home/ist/Proj/ApachePOI/datafiles/TestData.xlsx");
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    
    int rows = sheet.getLastRowNum();
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain why and how this code provides an answer to the question?